# SIP over WebSockets with Asterisk

Tags: websocket, asterisk

I would like to make a call from webbrowser using websockets along with sip5ml.js to an extension registered on asterisk. However, there is a limitation. The version of asterisk I am currently using has no native support for websockets, thus I need to come up with a workaround. Is there a way to forward all requests made from browser to asterisk?

Answer (score 1):

You need a SIP - WebRTC gateway. For example, this one: http://webrtc2sip.org/